# The project is not configured for Facelets yet in RAD 8.0

Tags: facelets

I am trying to create JSF 2 pages. When I create pages using facelets template I get message on top that "The project is not configured for Facelets yet.
 You need to add a Facelets runtime to the project's classpath".
I created file called Test1.xhtml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11  /DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com    /jsf/facelets"  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com /jsf/html">
 <h:head>
<title>Test1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="GENERATOR"
content="Rational® Application Developer for WebSphere® Software" />
  </h:head>
 <h:body>
 Test
 </h:body>
 </html>
```

When I run this I see same content of file in explorer, instead of Test.
Also Page code is not created for it.

Answer (score 1):

Page code and required web.xml/facesconfig stuf is created when you drop first component on the page.
Check this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21503733